# Oracle - Gap and Island on Two Columns

Tags: oracle

Initial data :

```
SELECT RCMOUVNT.MATRICULE, RCMOUVNT.DATENT, RCMOUVNT.DATOUT FROM RCMOUVNT
WHERE RCMOUVNT.MATRICULE = '81123404' order by DATENT asc;

MATRICULE   DATENT      DATOUT
81123404    04/09/17    30/11/17
81123404    01/12/17    31/07/18
81123404    01/02/19    31/01/20
```

Expected result using SQL :

```
MATRICULE   DATENT      DATOUT
81123404    04/09/17    31/07/18
81123404    01/02/19    31/01/20
```

I know this is a "gap and island" problem but I don't find any answer.

Comment: I've seen similiar questions on SO, though I couldn't find good example, but don't want to create a duplicate. Use analytic lag() and sum(), like in [this dbffiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b3006d4f4a658af6db5f845469c2eba).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution using theree steps

- find the distinct groups of records (each *breaking point* get assigned a new GRP_ID). Note that you must add 1 day to `DATAOUT` from previous row before the match with the `DATENT` to get your logik. Also the first row get a group automatically with the `NVL`.
- fill the NULLs in the groups (second subquery) - use `LAST_VALUE`
- aggregate per group (std GROUP BY) - third query uses `GROUP BY` and `MIN` resp. `MAX` to get the result.

.

```
with q1   as (
select 
  MATRICULE,
  DATENT,
  DATOUT, 
  case when (nvl(lag(DATOUT +1) over (partition by MATRICULE order by DATENT),DATE'2500-01-01') <> DATENT) then 
     row_number() over (partition by MATRICULE order by DATENT) end grp
from RCMOUVNT 
), q2 as (
select 
  MATRICULE,
  DATENT,
  DATOUT,
  grp,
  last_value(grp ignore nulls) over (partition by MATRICULE order by DATENT) as grp2
from q1
)   
select 
    MATRICULE,  
    min(DATENT) DATENT, 
    max(DATOUT) DATOUT
from q2
group by MATRICULE, grp2
order by 1

 MATRICULE DATENT              DATOUT             
---------- ------------------- -------------------
  81123404 04.09.2017 00:00:00 31.07.2018 00:00:00
  81123404 01.02.2019 00:00:00 31.01.2020 00:00:00
```